# How is that possible that Copious app can publish on wall without publish_stream permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Something very strange with this website copious.com, when you registered on this website via Facebook **the FB Copious App doesn't ask extended permission "publish_stream"**, on the following page you complete your registration on copious.com and you can choose " Post to my Facebook Wall that I joined Copious". So for testing I choose this option (**reminder: the App doesn't have the publish_stream permission**). And unreal few seconds after you will see on your wall a post with "I'm now discovering great finds on Copious.", message that all friends can see! How is that possible?

Comment: Are you sure they didn't request publish_actions permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this activity does not require publish_stream.  publish_actions gives the ability to publish to a user's feed as of 4/12.

Comment: it's not a FB action! it's really a post on the wall with :  "type": "link",
         "status_type": "app_created_story"

Anybody have information about this status_type = app_created_story ?

Comment: fb publish_action includes basic publish_stream access as of 4/25.  http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/04/25/streamlining-publish_stream-and-publish_actions-permissions/

Comment: You obviously get an upvote. Including a reference link would have been better though! ;)